# Como faço para deixar alguma imagem invisivel no love2d?

Tags: lua, love2d

Como faço para configurar a visibilidade de alguma imagem no Love2d? Como por exemplo, deixar ela 10% , 25% ou 50% visível.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma alternativa do meu comentário e minha resposta anterior é usar o método [setColor](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.setColor) antes de desenhar a imagem.

```
local opacidade = .5; -- de 0 à 1
love.graphics.setColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
    0xFF * opacidade);
```

Ou sem frações:

```
local opacidade = 255; // de 0 à 255
love.graphics.setColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, opacidade);
```

**Definindo a transparência**

No primeiro uso, a opacidade (transparência) é definida usando um número que vai de 0 até 1, que opcionalmente contém casas decimais. `0` é 0% visível e `1` é 100% visível. `.5` (ou `0.5`) é 50% visível. Isso pode ficar mais específico ainda, por exemplo: `.55559`.

No segundo uso, a opacidade é definida usando um número inteiro que vai de 0 até 255. `0` é 0% visível e `255` é 100% visível. `127` é praticamente 50% visível.

**Exemplo:**

```
local Imagem1, opacidade;

opacidade = .5; -- 50%

function love.load()
    Imagem1 = love.graphics.newImage 'test.png';
end

function love.draw()
    -- setColor vem antes...
    love.graphics.setColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0xFF * opacidade);
    -- de draw.
    love.graphics.draw(Imagem1);
end
```

**Exemplo repetindo a imagem 3 vezes:**

[image: duplicatas]

```
local imagem1;

function love.load()
    -- Carrega a imagem
    imagem1 = love.graphics.newImage 'test.png';
end

function love.draw()
    -- #Duplicata1 20% visível (No canto.)
    love.graphics.setColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, .2 * 0xFF);
    love.graphics.draw(imagem1);

    -- #Duplicata2 50% visível (No meio.)
    love.graphics.setColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, .5 * 0xFF);
    love.graphics.draw(imagem1, 150);

    -- #Duplicata3 100% visível (Em cima de todas.)
    love.graphics.setColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    love.graphics.draw(imagem1, 350);
end
```

Comment: como eu posso usá-lo?

Comment: @arthurgps2 Você se refere à definir a transparência?

Comment: anão deixa pra lá vc ja editou xD,mas uma coisa,vc escreveu esse codigo baseado em java?Eu reconheci por causa do ; no final de cada linha

Comment: @arthurgps2 Eu gosto de usar ele, e nop ! Não conheço profundamente Java, mas parece C#, que são ambas lindas linguagens :d

Comment: esta bem,alias por algum motivo,em vez de falar c sharp,eu falo c hashtag kkk,mas enfim obrigado

Comment: calma,agora estou com outra duvida.
É possivel deixar duas imagens,uma visivel completamente e outra apenas parcialmente?

Comment: @arthurgps2 Nesse caso você vai precisar rechamar o método setColor com o último argumento `255` (ou `0xFF`) antes de desenhar a imagem completamente visível (caso ela seja desenhada depois de uma imagem transparente).

Comment: voce pode me dar um exemplo?Desculpe se estou pedindo muita coisa de voce,e que ainda estou aprendendo LOVE2D...

Comment: @arthurgps2 Adicionei um exemplo

Answer (score 1):

Baseado em meu comentário, é possível definir a visibilidade de uma imagem copiando seus dados, mapeando seus pixels para modificar o campo alpha, e no fim criar outra imagem através dos dados modificados.

É preciso fazer isso apenas uma vez se for preciso definir a visibilidade.

### Demonstração

[image: db]

#### Esse exemplo deve funcionar com imagens comuns (BMP, JPEG e PNG):

```
local imagem2;

function love.load()
    -- Carrega a imagem
    local imagem1 = love.graphics.newImage 'test.png';

    -- Pega seus dados
    local imageData = imagem1:getData();

    --[=[ https://love2d.org/wiki/CompressedImageData
       Adiciona um erro para dados compressos
     * (dados compressos vem de imagens
     * do formato DXT1, DXT5, and BC5 / 3Dc, raramente usados).
     * Eu pessoalmente não sei que dados são e como funcionam.
     * O seu uso mais comum será BMP, JPEG ou PNG, creio eu. ]=]
    assert(not imagem1:isCompressed(),
        'Formato de imagem desconhecido');

    -- A opacidade vai de 0 até 1
    local opacidade = .2;

    -- Muda a opacidade de cada pixel
    imageData:mapPixel(function(x, y, r, g, b, a)
        return r, g, b, a * opacidade;
    end);

    imagem2 = love.graphics.newImage(imageData);
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(imagem2);
end
```

Comment: Ainda vou deixar essa resposta caso resolver algum problema do setColor.